# Multiple domains in one htaccess and have limited access to only one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't know if it is possible. I have three domains in one .htaccess and pointing to a shared location:

- domain-a.com
- domain-b.com
- domain-c.com

And now i want to block domain-c.com for all traffic and allow access from only two ip's. Domain-a.com and domain-b.com have to stay untouched.
I have tried to use this code in the .htaccess.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from x.x.x.x
```

I just don't know how to get it to work for one domain only instead of three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deny access to the domain , you can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain_c.com$
#--allowed ip(s)--#
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(ip1|ip2)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Tnx!!! At first it didn't work because i had put it somewhere in the middle. Than i have pasted it at the beginning of the file and it worked! :-)